# SublimeText remove empty lines

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have an HTML-file that lists all FontAwesome icons. Between the markup for each icon, there is a new line indented with spaces.

#### HTML

```
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> fa-cloud-upload</div>
            
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> fa-code</div>
            
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> fa-code-fork</div>
            
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> fa-coffee</div>
            
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> fa-cog</div>
```

#### Question

Which regex can I use to easily select these lines between the markup of all icons? It should only remove the empty lines and keep the indenting of lines containing markup.
I want to execute a find-and-replace with this regex in SublimeText.

#### Desired output

```
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> fa-cloud-upload</div>
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> fa-code</div>
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> fa-code-fork</div>
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> fa-coffee</div>
              <div class="fa-hover col-md-3 col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> fa-cog</div>
```

Comment: sorry for editing your question and removing the blank lines... apparently they're part of the question ;) i rolled the edit back. memo to self: read first, then edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for this pattern, and replace it by nothing.

```
\n\s*$
```

Remember to enable the regex mode in your search & replace.

Comment: Try  `^[\s]*?[\n\r]+` for empty lines along with whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex:

```
^\s*$[\r\n]+
```

And replace with nothing.

`^` matches the beginning of the line, `\s*` matches any potential space, tabs and such, `$` will match the end of the line.

The next `[\r\n]+` is to bring back the next line into the current line and will match newlines and carriage returns.

Comment: It worked for one line, but then stopped working. Not sure why. The answer of @zessx does the trick so I'll go with that one. Thanks!

Comment: @Voles Huh, weird... Oh well, glad you have your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are truly empty, and doesn't contain any spaces or tabs, then `^$` should be enough. The `^` character matches the beginning of a line, and `$` matches the end of a line.

Comment: The empty lines do contain spaces for indenting, so `^$` doesn't work.